# Importxml formula to help scraping from web solving paging problem

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, paging

The site i am trying to scrape from is a marketplace with a number of pages with output results.
When scraping the importxml formula is valid for the defined page (e.g. [https://cars.av.by/filter?brands[0][brand]=6&brands[0][model]=1992&year[min]=2010&year[max]=2018&page=3](https://cars.av.by/filter?brands%5B0%5D%5Bbrand%5D=6&brands%5B0%5D%5Bmodel%5D=1992&year%5Bmin%5D=2010&year%5Bmax%5D=2018&page=3))

Is there any solution for importxml formula tp get data from all pages?

the same request was here:
[list with multiple autogenerated importxml queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299204/list-with-multiple-autogenerated-importxml-queries)

My formula example for page 1:
=FLATTEN(IMPORTXML("https://cars.av.by/filter?brands[0][brand]=6&brands[0][model]=1992&year[min]=2010&year[max]=2018&page=1","//main//h3/a"))

Comment: share your formula

Comment: =FLATTEN(IMPORTXML("https://cars.av.by/filter?brands[0][brand]=6&brands[0][model]=1992&year[min]=2010&year[max]=2018&page=1","//main//h3/a"))

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(BYROW(A1&SEQUENCE(20), 
 LAMBDA(x, "×"&TEXTJOIN("×", 1, IMPORTXML(x, "//main//h3/a"))))),,9^9), "×")))
```

[image]

Comment: It does work! Thank you so much. )) But i would like to admit that your formula is advanced. I need time to understand it))

Comment: i have found a following bug. Your formula scrapes 67 items but i see 68 on the site?

Comment: @AndreiRusak I got 68: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtO89.png

Comment: seems that it is woking. but sometimes with strange tail in the cell @Loading...Loading...Loading...@

Comment: here there is a link to a file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hoYEK35Ljyiae8Bry6nMHKmNGBLwFZ6DqFwUGVJJMWk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(HLOOKUP("×", {"×"; QUERY(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN({
 IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(B1&"&page=1", "//div[@class='listing__items']/div/div/div"), 9^9, 3), {"","",""}); 
 IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(B1&"&page=2", "//div[@class='listing__items']/div/div/div"), 9^9, 3), {"","",""}); 
 IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(B1&"&page=3", "//div[@class='listing__items']/div/div/div"), 9^9, 3), {"","",""}); 
 IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(B1&"&page=4", "//div[@class='listing__items']/div/div/div"), 9^9, 3), {"","",""}); 
 IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(B1&"&page=5", "//div[@class='listing__items']/div/div/div"), 9^9, 3), {"","",""})}), ", ", ))), 
 "where Col1 is not null and not Col1 ends with 'VIN' and not Col1 contains 'ТОП'", )}, 
 SEQUENCE(5*ROWS(B:B)/11, 11, 2), ), " г.| \$$|^≈ ", ), 
 "select Col1,Col3,Col8,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col10 where Col1 is not null and not Col1 = '#REF!'", ))
```

[image: 0]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Lu4V-QN875LpuiZSu6vqDJ7_EBDok8XPalBq5T91LY/copy)